# Existence of solution to first order ODE. What is there to be proved?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$\bf Theorem$

> Let $I$ be an interval of the real line. Let $f(t,x)$ be Lipschitz on $x$ on $I\times \Bbb R$. Let $\tau\in I, \xi\in \Bbb R$. If $\tau$ is interior in $I$,  there exists $\lambda>0$ and $x: [\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda] \subset I\to \Bbb R$ such that $$x'(t)=f(t,x)\\x(\tau)=\xi$$

Then follows the proof saying that a solution is given by $x(t)=\xi+\int^t_\tau f(s,x(s))ds$ and it shows how to construct this by approximating it by a sequence of functions that uniformly converge to it.

I don't understand why this is needed, isn't it obvious that the mentioned $x(t)$ is a solution? Why does this require a proof (or, which part of this requires it?)?

$\bf Proof$

> The construction method will then be finding a solution to the integral equation. We'll do this by defining inductively:
>   $$x_0(t)=\xi \\ x_1(t) = \xi + \int ^t_\tau f(s, x_0(s))ds\\ x_k(t) = \xi + \int_\tau^t f(s,x_{k-1})ds$$
>   If we prove that the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $x(t)$, we'll have that $x(t)$  is continuous on $[\tau-\lambda,\tau+\lambda] $ and that it is a solution to the ODE.
>   $$x_{k+1}-x_k =\int_\tau^t (f(s,x_{k})-f(s,x_{k-1}))ds $$
>
> Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $f$. Then, for $t\geq \tau$:
>   $$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq L \int_\tau^t |x_{k+1}-x_k|ds$$
>
> Now, let $\lambda\leq \frac 1{2L}$, $I_\lambda:= [\tau - \lambda, \tau + \lambda]\subset I$, then:
>
> $$\max\{|x_{k+1}(t) − x_k(t)| , t ∈ [τ, τ + λ]\} ≤ L|t − τ | \max\{|x_k(t) − x_{k−1}(t)| , t ∈ [τ, τ + λ]\}\\ ≤ \frac 12 \max\{|x_{k}(t) − x_{k−1}(t)| , t ∈ [τ, τ + λ]\}$$
>    An analogous inequality  is reached on the interval $[\tau - \lambda, \tau]$
>
> Let us now call $m_k= \max\{|x_k-x_{k-1}|, t \in I_\lambda\}$. We then have:
>
> $$
> m_{k+1} \leq \frac 1 2 m_k
> $$
>   Iterating this inequality:
>
> $$m_k \leq \frac 1 {2^{k-1}}m_1$$
>
> Finally, if $j=k+m$:
>   $$|x_k(t) − x_j (t)| = |x_k(t) − x_{k+m}(t)| = |\sum_{i=0}^{m−1}
> (xk+i(t) − xk+i+1(t))| ≤ \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}m_{k+i+1}  ≤ \frac  {m_1}{2^k} \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac {1}{2^i} \leq \frac {m_1}{2^{k-1}}$$
>
> Then, let $\epsilon > 0 $, if $j,k\geq k_0$, where $\frac {m_1}{2^{k_0-1}}< \epsilon$, we have:
>   $$
> |x_j(t)-x_k(t)| < \epsilon
> $$

How correct is this proof? I understood from the comments that I don't really know how to calculate the $x$ from the given integral equation, but what says I know how to calculate the functions $x_i$ from the sequence?

Comment: In $\int_{\tau}^t f(s,x(s))\,ds$, what is $x(s)$? You're using $x$ to define $x$. That is a problem.

Comment: I added a bit more about the paper. Maybe that makes it clearer?

Comment: The usual thing is a) note that $x$ is a solution of the differential equation $x'(t) = f(t,x(t))$ with initial value $x(\tau) = \xi$ if and only if $x$ is a solution of the integral equation $x(t) = \xi + \int_{\tau}^t f(s,x(s))\,ds$. Then comes part b), showing the existence of a solution. That is easier in the integral equation form. And because of that we bothered with introducing the integral equation.

Comment: I don't understand why showing that a solution for that exists requires a proof, doesn't having $f$ continuous suffice for the integral to exist, and thus $x(t)$?

Comment: But you don't yet _have_ $x$. So you don't have anything to put into $f(s,\,\cdot\,)$ at first. Then you go and show that the operator $$y \mapsto \biggl(t \mapsto \xi + \int_{\tau}^t f(s,y(s))\,ds\biggr)$$ has a fixed point.

Comment: Yes, you can also do that, take the theorem of Peano and stack the Gronwall lemma on to provide uniqueness. But it is a much more organic solution to get all at once from the Banach fixed-point theorem.

Comment: I'll go ahead and post the entire proof in a while, I'm uncertain it's entirely correct. Why would the limit of the sequence I posted converge to a solution of the equation? I understand why the sequence must converge and all that, but I don't get how the limit is necessarily a solution to the integral equation.

Comment: Try to write down the integral for some simple $f$: for example $f(t, x) = x$. Then try if you can explicitly compute the integral.

Comment: A similar question: Question: Show that there is $x$ so that $x = \cos x$ Wrong answer: Let $x = \cos x$, then this $x$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa. That really helped me understand my mistake. I added the full proof given by my text.

Comment: Note that in the proof, it is shown that $\{x_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C(I_\lambda)$. As $C(I_\lambda)$ is complete, $\{x_k\}$ converges to some $x(t)$. Then it should be claimed that this $x(t)$ satisfies the integral equality (just let $k \to \infty$ on both sides of the equation defining $x_{k+1}$)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the $x_k$ since they are the anti-derivatives of a (composite) continuous function.

If you are in the situation where the domain is a stripe $I×\Bbb R$ with a global Lipschitz constant $L$, then you can use the modified equivalent supremums norm
$$
\|x\|_L=\sup_{t\in I} e^{-2L|t-τ|}\|x(t)\|
$$
for the full interval $I$, no sub-interval selection necessary.

Careful computation (or a shift of the $t$ axis so that $τ=0$) shows with relative ease that in that norm
$$
\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|_L\le\frac12\|x_k-x_{k-1}\|_L
$$
or in general that the Picard integral operator is contractive with factor $\frac12$.

Now existence and uniqueness follows as with your proof via or along the lines of the Banach fixed point theorem.