# Global Existence of ODE Solution, when Lipschitz-estimate is global?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$, that is continuous in the first argument and there exists a constant $L>0$, s.t. for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $y,y'\in\mathbb{R}^d$ one has the inequality
\begin{equation}
\lvert f(t,y) - f(t,y')\rvert \leq L\cdot\lvert y-y'\rvert.
\end{equation}

I want to prove (as a corollary to the classical Picard-Lindelöf Theorem), that for the ODE
\begin{equation}
\dot{y}(t) = f(t,y(t)),\quad t\in\: ]0,1[
\end{equation}
with an initial value $y(0)=y_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$, one can find a unique solution $y:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^d$, that can be extended to the real line, meaning
\begin{equation}
\dot{y}(t) = f(t,y(t)),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

For a local Lipschitz-estimate on $f$ we get existence of a solution on some bounded interval. I am interested in the extension part of this statement. The idea is that a global Lipschitz-estimate should allow this extension, but I am not quite sure how to come about this. Can someone help? A suitable reference would also be nice, as I am sure that someone has thought about this before.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448107/showing-global-lipschitz-implies-global-solution-ode for a direct answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587806/picards-existence-theorem-successive-approximations-and-the-global-solution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347599/questions-about-the-picard-lindel%c3%b6f-theorem-for-an-ode and the links in my answer to the last.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.