# Show that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 5y +28 \cos(y), y(0) = 54$ has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Show that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 5y +28 \cos(y), y(0) = 54$ has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is a spin off of one of the problems in Berkeley Problems in Mathematics.

My solution (attempt) is quite alot shorter than the one presented by the authours ( they show that a unique solution exists on some neighbourhood of $(0,54)$ using a local version of Picard's theorem and then use IFT to find an explicit solution on this neighbourhood and prove that this solution is valid on $\mathbb{R}$) so I wanted to check that I hadn't missed something.

Here is my solution:

Let $f(x,y)= 5y +28\cos(y)$. Fix $h >0$. By basic properties of continuous functions $f$ is continuous on $[-h,h] \times \mathbb{R}$ and moreover Lipschitz in $y$ on this strip. This follows from,

$|f_y (x,y)|=|5-28\sin(y)| \leq 5+28|\sin(y)| \leq 5+28 = 33$  and the MVT.

Picard's theorem applies and we see that the IVP has a unique solution on $[-h,h]$.

But $h$ was arbitrary so the IVP has a solution on all of $\mathbb{R}$. $\blacksquare$

Is this correct? In general I am bit unsure about how to prove the uniqueness/existence of global solutions... [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Global_uniqueness_and_maximum_domain_of_solution) or global Picard?!

---

Note the version of Picard's theorem I am using is

The IVP $y'(x) = f(x,y), y(a)=b$, has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$ provided, $\forall h:$

- $f$ is continuous on $[a-h, a+h] \times \mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is Lipschitz in y on $[a-h, a+h] \times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct. With a sub-linear right side you get a global solution. The proof idea is explored for instance in

- [Existence of solution to first order ODE. What is there to be proved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521479/115115)
- [Inequality in the proof of unique solution of an ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205447/115115)

The problem with your source might be that they did not give the effort to prove this more global version of the theorem after the standard localized one. Thus they have to assemble the solution from many local solutions.

Note that with the formulation of your condition, you only get a solution on $[a-h,a+h]$, which should be no surprise as this is the explored domain of the ODE.

Comment: Many thanks! What you said about my source sounds about right ( they give another solution where they "patch together" local solutions much as you suggested). I don't quite understand your last line. If you don't mind, could you elaborate please?

Comment: If you assume the global Lipschitz condition etc. on the strip $I\times\Bbb R$, then you can maximally get a solution on $I$. If $I=\Bbb R$, then obviously you get an unrestricted solution.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't this suggest that my approach is incorrect, as although I get a unique solution on any interval containing zero I can't make the jump to $\mathbb{R}$? Or are you immediately applying Picard's theorem on $\mathbb{R}$. If so, I didn't know this is possible...

Comment: Why not? As the equation is autonomous, the Lipschitz condition is valid globally for $I=\Bbb R$. The global existence theorem also applies to this situation.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you again, your post has helped me alot!

Comment: Just the one you cited, if $f:I\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuous and globally Lipschitz in the second argument, then $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$, $x_0\in I$ has a unique solution $y:I\to\Bbb R^n$. The proof shows the contractivity of the Picard iteration in the modified norm $\|y\|=\sup_{x\in I}e^{-2L|x-x_0|}\|y(x)\|$ as discussed in the links.

Comment: I just realised what I was missing, I believe! It isn't necessary to work with closed intervals in Picard's theorem and we can also work with open intervals, right? This would allow $I = \mathbb{R}$ for instance, resolving my issues.